# Getting Unexpected token in JSON error while using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an error. I am getting the following error while calling json data using `$http` in Angular.js.

Error:

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    in JSON at position 991
    at Object.parse (native)
        at Object.parse (native)
        at wc (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:17:36)
        at dc (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:91:424)
        at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:92:337
        at q (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:7:355)
        at gd (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:92:319)
        at c (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:94:72)
        at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:130:409
        at m.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:107)
        at m.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js:142:173
)
```

I am providing my code below.

customer.json:

```
[
  {
    "rest_name": "Anjum",
    "id":"1",
     "address":"Goa",
     "city":"1",
     "country":"India",
    " date":"2016-07-05 11:39:04",
     "image":"",
     "member_id":"135",
     "mobile":"9937229853",
     "person":"Subhrajyoti pradhan",
     "postal":"752109",
     "premium":"1",
     "proviance":"Goa",
     "quad_id":"3",
     "quadrant":"3",
     "quadrant_name":"SW",
     "status":"1",
     "url":"http://orimark.com"
  },{
   " rest_name": "A&P Chinese Food Express",
     "id":"2",
     "address":"Goa",
     "city":"1",
     "country":"India",
    " date":"2016-07-05 11:39:04",
     "image":"",
     "member_id":"135",
     "mobile":"9937229853",
     "person":"Subhrajyoti pradhan",
     "postal":"752109",
     "premium":"1",
     "proviance":"Goa",
     "quad_id":"3",
     "quadrant":"3",
     "quadrant_name":"SW",
     "status":"1",
     "url":"http://orimark.com"
  },{
   " rest_name": "Bookers BBQ & Crab Shack",
     "id":"3",
     "address":"Goa",
     "city":"1",
     "country":"India",
    " date":"2016-07-05 11:39:04",
     "image":"",
     "member_id":"135",
     "mobile":"9937229853",
     "person":"Subhrajyoti pradhan",
     "postal":"752109",
     "premium":"1",
     "proviance":"Goa",
     "quad_id":"3",
     "quadrant":"3",
     "quadrant_name":"SW",
     "status":"1",
     "url":"http://orimark.com"
  },{
    "rest_name": "Butcher And The Baker",
     "id":"4",
     "address":"Goa",
     "city":"1",
     "country":"India",
    " date":"2016-07-05 11:39:04",
     "image":"",
     "member_id":"135",
     "mobile":"9937229853",
     "person":"Subhrajyoti pradhan",
     "postal":"752109",
     "premium":"1",
     "proviance":"Goa",
     "quad_id":"3",
     "quadrant":"3",
     "quadrant_name":"SW",
     "status":"1",
     "url":"http://orimark.com"
  },{
    "rest_name": "Cactus Club Stephen Avenue",
     "id":"5",
      "address":"Goa",
     "city":"1",
     "country":"India",
    " date":"2016-07-05 11:39:04",
     "image":"",
     "member_id":"135",
     "mobile":"9937229853",
     "person":"Subhrajyoti pradhan",
     "postal":"752109",
     "premium":"1",
     "proviance":"Goa",
     "quad_id":"3",
     "quadrant":"3",
     "quadrant_name":"SW",
     "status":"1",
     "url":"http://orimark.com"
  },{
    "rest_name": "Cactus Club - Macleod Trail",
    " id":"6",
      "address":"Goa",
     "city":"1",
     "country":"India",
    " date":"2016-07-05 11:39:04",
     "image":"",
     "member_id":"135",
     "mobile":"9937229853",
     "person":"Subhrajyoti pradhan",
     "postal":"752109",
     "premium":"1",
     "proviance":"Goa",
     "quad_id":"3",
     "quadrant":"3",
     "quadrant_name":"SW",
     "status":"1",
     "url":"http://orimark.com"
  }
  ]
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
 $http.get('customer.json').success(function(data) {
    console.log('data',data);
    $scope.listOfCustomerData=data;
  })
```

My view code is given below.

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
      <tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name:startsWith | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Post your view code, Maybe the problem is there, your JSON looks ok.

Comment: Could be your `" date"` keys (and other keys with leading spaces)

Comment: I have updated my post please check.

Comment: @Phil : You are right.Now its working.

Comment: Strange, I said that but accordingly the JSON validator it was correct.. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Yes,i have also tasted there,it was correct but what @phil was saing it gave me the perfect solution.

Comment: try `console.log(data.data)` and which version of chrome you are using?

Comment: what is the version of angular you are using ?

Comment: i am using `Version 51.0.2704.106 m` of chrome.

Comment: I am using angular.js version `1.4.6`.

Comment: I think it should be `data.data`

Comment: please explain why are you using $parent.label result ?? also please explain for what purpose you wraped it within in double (())

Comment: is there any other code you have left out just because you think its unnecessary, because I've got this working but i can't figure out why is it giving unexpected json token error

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided above is working fine, the problem is some where else, probably in the code which you have left out because you think its unnecessary. so obviously I don't know why are you getting "`Unexpected token in JSON at position 991`" also you said you are using 1.4.6 whereas your error says you are using 1.5.6.

Also a suggestion you could simply do:

```
<tr dir-paginate="cus in listOfCustomerData | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
```

Instead of making it complicated:

```
<tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name:startsWith | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:pageSize track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
```

[Here is the working plunker i made](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Fql1ONurlTnloQSEYvu)